# can't get out of while after signal use

Tags: c, while-loop, signals

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigint_handler(int);

int  main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

     while (1){
         pause();
     }
    printf("Out..\n");
    return 0;
}

 void sigint_handler(int sig)
{

    printf("killing process %d\n",getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

I dont get: Out... after ctrl+c
So never returns on while or getting out. How can i fix it, to continiue in main, and print "Out..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont get: Out... after ctrl+c

Because the signal handler immediately ends the process so `main` never gets the chance of actually doing the printf. I suspect you don't actually want to `exit` in the handler. You should take the `pause` out of the loop and wait until the signal gets delivered.

**This isn't the best way of waiting for a signal.** For starters it is conceivable that the user could send the SIGINT before you get the chance to `pause`. The signal would be lost and `pause(2)` would block until the end of time.

You should probably use `sigsuspend` or the simpler `sigpause`.

Comment: i want to wait for signal (ctrl+c mayby i'll put a scanf before and then i want to print "Out.."

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I think you've provided a list of *safe* functions. Reentrant functions are callable from a signal handler. And `_exit` is  of course async-signal-safe (`exit` isn't).

Comment: Yes safe functions!... and [calling exit() in signal handler is safe](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/signal_handling.html) ...thanks Cnicutar!..your given a good answer..I just struct in printf..

Answer (score 2):

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigint_handler(int);

int  main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);


     pause();

    printf("Out..\n");
    return 0;
}

 void sigint_handler(int sig)
{

    printf("killing process %d\n",getpid());
    //exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `printf` in sigint_handler, it may be undefined behavior.  [The list of safe functions that can be call in signal handler man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html).
Explanation: [**Use reentrant functions for safer signal handling**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent/index.html#N101CA)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loop in `main()` to exit under control, you have to make it a non-infinite loop.  I'd probably do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t sig_received = 0;
void sigint_handler(int);

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    while (sig_received == 0)
        pause();
    printf("Out..\n");
    return 0;
}

void sigint_handler(int sig)
{
    sig_received = sig;
}
```

This meets the requirements of the C standard, which are far more stringent on what you're allowed to do in signal handlers than POSIX is.